# How to get the base URL in AspNetCore webapi?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I'm writing a hybrid MVC and WebApi app using netcoreapp3.1.

The MVC pages render reports and the one and only webapi method converts the HTML obtained using a URL to a PDF. Since the MVC pages have the same base URL as the WebApi I'd like to pick this up at run-time rather than make it a setting.

Once upon a time I would obtained the URL using HttpContext, but AspNetCore WebApi classes don't seem to *have* this.

Is there a request object? If not, is there some other way to get the URL for the currently executing API method?

Comment: There is no real way to get the base URL since it can be controlled through an external source like a proxy server. The only reliable ways are to use a setting or inspect the current request to check what URL was called.

Comment: I hope this will help [Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: @DavidG "inspect the current request" yes, how?

Comment: See the other comment and to something like `httpContext.Request.Host`

Answer (score 0):

GoodboY's comment led to an answer.

In `startup.cs` you can add an HttpContextAccessor object to the injectable services.

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); 
    }
```

Then in your WebApi controller you can inject it.

```cs
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public PdfController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
```

Then in a WebApi method of this controller you can obtain `Request` like so

```cs
      var Request = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
```